# org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingPropertyExceptionNoStack: No such property: resourceResolver for class: griffon.swing.SwingApplet

Tags: applet, griffon

Im having problem to run griffon applet in the browser when i package it to applet. this error was occurred when browser try to execute my applet:-

**org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingPropertyExceptionNoStack: No such property: resourceResolver for class: griffon.swing.SwingApplet**

my html page like this :-

```
<script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var attributes = {id: 'Mocha',
                      codebase:'http://localhost:8080/testapplet/applet',
                      code:'griffon.swing.SwingApplet',
                      archive:'griffon-swing-runtime-1.2.0.jar,griffon-rt-1.2.0.jar,groovy-all-2.0.6.jar,jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar,jul-to-slf4j-1.7.2.jar,log4j-1.2.17.jar,mocha.jar,slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar,slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar',
                      width:'320', height:'240'} ;
    var parameters = {fontSize:16,
                      java_arguments: "-Djnlp.packEnabled=false",
                      //jnlp_href:'http://localhost:8080/testapplet/applet/applet.jnlp',
                      draggable:'true',
                      image:'griffon.png',
                      boxmessage:'Loading Mocha',
                      boxbgcolor:'#FFFFFF', boxfgcolor:'#000000',
                      codebase_lookup: 'false'} ;
    var version = '1.5.0' ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

my applet.jnlp :-

```
<jnlp
    version="0.1"
    codebase="http://localhost:8080/testapplet/applet"
    href="applet.jnlp"
>
    <information>
        <title>mocha 0.1</title>
        <vendor>cipon</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/testapplet"/>
        <!--fallback description-->
        <description>mocha 0.1</description>
        <description kind="one-line">mocha 0.1</description>
        <description kind="short">mocha 0.1</description>
        <description kind="tooltip">mocha 0.1</description>
        <!-- default icon -->
        <icon href="griffon-icon-64x64.png" kind="default" width="64" height="64"/>
        <!-- icon used for splash screen -->
        <icon href="griffon.png" kind="splash" width="391" height="123"/>
        <!-- icon used in selected -->
        <icon href="griffon-icon-64x64.png" kind="selected" width="64" height="64"/>
        <!-- icon used on disabled -->
        <icon href="griffon-icon-64x64.png" kind="disabled" width="64" height="64"/>
        <!-- icon used on rollover -->
        <icon href="griffon-icon-64x64.png" kind="rollover" width="64" height="64"/>
        <!-- icon used on shortcut -->
        <icon href="griffon-icon-64x64.png" kind="shortcut" width="64" height="64"/>
<!-- to create shortcuts, uncomment this
        <shortcut online="true">
            <desktop/>
            <menu submenu="Mocha"/>
        </shortcut>
-->
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
        <!--<j2ee-application-client-permissions/>-->
    </security>
    <resources>
        <property name="griffon.runmode" value="applet"/>
        <property name="jnlp.packEnabled" value="true"/>
        <j2se version="1.5+" />
        <!-- auto-added jars follow, griffon-rt, app, and groovy -->
        <jar href='griffon-swing-runtime-1.2.0.jar' main='true'/>
        <jar href='griffon-rt-1.2.0.jar'/>
        <jar href='groovy-all-2.0.6.jar'/>
        <jar href='jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar'/>
        <jar href='jul-to-slf4j-1.7.2.jar'/>
        <jar href='log4j-1.2.17.jar'/>
        <jar href='mocha.jar' main='false' />
        <jar href='slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar'/>
        <jar href='slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar'/>
        <!-- Add all extra jars below here, or the app may break -->


    </resources>

  <applet-desc
      documentbase="http://localhost:8080/testapplet/applet"
      name="MochaApplet"
      main-class="griffon.swing.SwingApplet"
      width="320"
      height="240">
      <!-- params are ignored when referenced from web page for 6u10 -->
    <!--<param name="key1" value="value1"/>-->
    <!--<param name="key2" value="value2"/>-->

  </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

thank you.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more of information on your environment? I was able to reproduce the problem with MacOSX 1.7.5, Firefox 19.0.2, Java Plug-in 11.0.2.77, JRE 1.8.0-ea-b77

Comment: i'm using mac os x 10.8.3, safari 6.0.3, browser JRE 1.7.0_17.

Comment: Just to be sure, the error only occurs if loading the applet on a browser, not when running it with "griffon run-applet", right?

Comment: yes, only on browser .run_applet working fine.

Comment: Just to let you know I have not forgotten about this issue. Had no luck running with a virtualized Ubuntu and Firefox (applet failed to show without errors on the console) and my Windows VM is busted. Would you care for registering a ticket at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/griffon ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been identified and fixed, see https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRIFFON-641 for more info. Turns out that `griffon.swing.AbstractSwingApplet` did not expose `resourceResolver` as it should. Version 1.3.1 of the `swing` plugin fixes the problem.